# How can I run a forEach loop against a specific section inside a tableview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
        if (tableView.Root.Count > 1) {
            foreach (var section in tableView.Root)
            {
                foreach (var cell in section)
                {
                    cell.Tapped -= openCategoriesPage;
                }
            }
            tableView.Root.RemoveAt(1);
        }
```

Rather than run the foreach for each section in tableView.Root, is there a way that I can run it for only the 2nd section?

Putting it another way. Is there a way that I can get a handle on the 2nd section in tableView? So I can eliminate the need for two forEach loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableRoot` is inherited from ....IList, ICollection, IEnumerable... so use the `index`

```
foreach (var cell in tableView.Root[1])
{
   cell.Tapped -= openCategoriesPage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you help